# Android Date Conversion

Tags: java, android, date, time

I'm receiving some date format, an ISO-something, and was wondering what the appropriate way to parse it into a timestamp.

My ultimate goal will be a standard switch on it to create "X minutes / hours / days ago.", so if there is a tool that does that already, that'd be optimal.

I've tried joda-time, but it choked on it.

Here is an example of a time string:

`2012-05-03 @ 15.55.05.433Z`

Additionally, if it is indeed it is the case that it's not an ISO-something format, I've no problem manipulating, say, the `@` out of it, etc.

**EDIT:** Attempt 1:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" );

try
{
  Date myDate = dateFormat.parse( o.getCreationDate().replace( "@", "" ) );

  long minutes = myDate.getTime() / 1000 / 60;

  holder.timeText.setText( minutes + " minutes ago" );
}
catch( ParseException e )
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result:

`05-17 16:58:05.003: W/System.err(2915): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-05-09  19:49:47.987Z" (at offset 24)`

**EDIT 2:** Stripping the Z, and correct millisecond to minute conversion fixed it:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" );

try
{
  Date myDate = dateFormat.parse( o.getCreationDate().replace( "@ ", "" ).replace( "Z", "" ) );

  Date now = new Date();

  long minutes = ( now.getTime() - myDate.getTime() ) / 1000 / 60;

  holder.timeText.setText( minutes + " minutes ago" );
}
catch( ParseException e )
{
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Google for ISO8601 - I don't think the `@` symbol is part of that however but it's been a while since I read the RFCs. As Gokhan answered - you can use a SimpleDateFormat to parse it (probably without the @) into a usable Android Date and then re-format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove the `@` character, then create an instance of `SimpleDateFormat` that will parse your string and return a `Date` object which will enable you to get the timestamp you desire.

```
String myStringDate = "2012-05-03 @ 15.55.05.433Z";
       myStringDate = myStringDate.replace("@ ","");   //Also removes extra whitespace  

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date myDate = dateFormat.parse("your date string");
     myDate.getTime(); //Your timestamp in milliseconds
```

**Note** you'll need to surround with a try and catch since it can throw an exception.

Comment: The time format of the OP's example is in HH.mm.ss.SSSZ where HH is 24 hour clock - using `hh` will fail with 15 for the hour. SSS is fractional seconds (milliseconds). Normally after Z there would be an offset such as +0100 or similar but Z on its own refers to UTC. Also, are you sure that SimpleDateFormat will handle that @ symbol?

Comment: Fixed the format, and just removing the `@` in case it doesn't handle it. I can't test it though, I'm not at home. Thanks for the lower case hh's though @MisterSquonk

Comment: @thisMayhem: I've edited my post, it still is throwing an exception.

Comment: Index 24 is the end of your string, maybe you've left the extra whitespace in your string? Note how there is one on each side of `@`

Comment: @thisMayhem: My bad (slightly misleading with `Z`). It is valid for a `SimpleDateFormat` when using it to `format(...)` a `String` from a `Date` but it's not valid for the opposite, i.e., when using `parse(...)` to create a `Date` from a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Use SimpleDateFormat. Take a look at [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToDate.shtml)

Comment: How would I go about getting my String into the Date though? It seems as though it's just using NOW, rather than a supplied, parsed string. My problem isn't working with formatting, it's parsing.